# Does light photons have jerk?

Tags: visible-light, speed-of-light, photons, acceleration, jerk

While searching in web regarding whether rate of change of acceleration is possible or not; I came across the concept of [jerk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_%28physics%29). I want to know whether photons which can be accelerated can also have jerk or not?

Comment: -1: This is not a good question. The answer is "sort of".

Comment: hey ron, i am not a physicist just out of curiosity i have asked this question and i believe that no questions are stupid and every question has an answer

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20289/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking light can't be accelerated. Viewed from a local frame it always travels at a speed of $c$ and in a straight line. Since the acceleration is always zero the jerk is also always zero.

Light can be bent by gravitational fields, i.e. in curved space-time, and therefore it is accelerated in the sense that it's velocity changes direction so I suppose the jerk is non-zero. However the bending of light we see is just the result of the curvature of spacetime. Viewed locally the light travels in a straight line at constant velocity, so it's not clear to me that jerk is an especially useful concept in calculating the trajectory of a light beam.