# Does light initially accelerate?

Tags: special-relativity, photons, speed-of-light

Light travels with a speed of $3\times10^8{m\over s}$. My question is that was the light initially accelerating or it archived the speed in an instance? If it was accelerating then why it did not accelerate beyond that?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20289/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Asker what on Earth are lakh and crore anyway?! They sound like squidgy creatures who live at the bottom of very deep oceans.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance [it's on the internet so it must be true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh)