# Is there any acceleration of light?

Tags: visible-light, photons, speed-of-light, acceleration

I find it hard to believe that photons always travel with 3 x 10^8 m/s just from the start. But there must be some acceleration of light. Maybe huge or taking place in picoseconds. So what maybe the acceleration of light or photons?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94049/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20289/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/111189/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/121421/2451 and links therein.

Comment: A general hint: "I find it hard to believe" is something you can say about most quantum phenomena. This does not mean they are not the way they are. It just means the human mind is incredibly ill-suited to grasp quantum mechanics/relativity on an intuitive level.