# Where does light get its speed from?

Tags: special-relativity, photons, speed-of-light

One source of light is, IIRC my high school physics, when an excited electron jumps back to its normal position. This jump generates a photon. How can an event like that shoot of a particle at the speed of light? Why isn't it this photon moving much slower? Other particles can move at almost the speed of light but typically is much slower..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can a photon have no mass and still travel at the speed of light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3541/)

Comment: There is a reason we can talk about *the speed of light*, but you never hear anyone say *the speed of electrons* or *the speed of apples* etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does a photon instantaneously gain $c$ speed when emitted from an electron?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94049/)