# Does light accelerate at origin?

Tags: special-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, acceleration, speed-of-light

Put simply: I light a candle and there is light. Whether a photon or something else: what is its speed and how and when did it get that speed?

I am aware of: [Do photons have acceleration?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20289/)
and [Does a photon instantaneously gain $c$ speed when emitted from an electron?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94049/)

But couldn't extract an answer that I understand from it.

Comment: The accepted answer to [Do photons have acceleration?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20289) is flat-out wrong. Ignore it. The other answers to that question are much better.

Comment: Hi, I've closed your question because it is an obvious duplicate. If you can edit your question to make clear exactly what aspects of the answers to the previous question are unclear then we can reopen your question.

Comment: The photon should come into existence as it is. All answers to the linked question focus on some other part, ie the lifetime of the state from which the photon is emitted. As soon as emitted, it moves at c, in vacuum.