# Speed of light exiting a prism

Tags: optics, photons, acceleration, speed-of-light, refraction

When light travels through a medium, even a sparse medium, it slows down from the speed of light in vacuum to the speed of light in that medium.
When that light re-enters a true vacuum, it will resume moving at the speed of light in a vacuum.

1. Why the light doesn't keep the same speed it had when it was in the prism, when it excite the prism ?
2. Is the acceleration instantaneous at the exit of the prism ?
3. What makes the light keep going and not slowing down and stopping ?

[image]

Comment: You should actually study what happens when light enters a medium. There is a good explanation [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/466/what-is-the-mechanism-behind-the-slowdown-of-light-photons-in-a-transparent-medi).

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11820/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/466/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20289/2451 and links therein.