# Does light accelerate?

Tags: special-relativity, photons, acceleration, speed-of-light, refraction

If considering the general formula for acceleration, ie.
Δ V/ΔT, we would get zero as the velocity of light is constant and does not change.

However, what about when photons travel through different media? Wouldn't the speed change here?

My understanding is, of course, flawed here. I'm still in high school, so would appreciate some conceptual clarity.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20289/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic I did check out the 'related questions' list but seems like I missed this one. Thanks for the link.